# How to create an ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.

I am using target=android-18.

I want to create new Action Bar or modify existing action bar.

Pls help me.

thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

In your menu xml res/menu/menu.xml

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_item"
android:title="action_title"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:showAsAction="always" /> /* showAsAction! */
```

Add something like that

Comment: Also, did you read Android documentation ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

For creating actionBar you would require to use Fragments.
You could refer to the below links for your heads up
[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html) and [Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Suppose you want to customize your actionBar, you could refer [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html).